# XamNumericEditor with mask copying minutes from hours

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, mask, timespan

I've run into this issue, and can't seem to find a solution for it.

As far as I know the mask is fine.

The issue is that the minutes get copied from the hours. I enter the minutes, and on focus lost they change into the hour's value. Or if i change the hour, the minutes change also.

The property is bound to a TimeSpan type.

The xaml:

```
<igE:XamNumericEditor Grid.Row="5"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Mask="hh:mm"
                        Value="{Binding Timeee, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                        ValueType="core:TimeSpan"
                        Margin="0"/>
```

Anybody got any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey. There seems to be a bug with the type TimeSpan.

With DateTime it works fine.